# How can I leverage my GPU with this ffmpeg command?

Tags: ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I need to [extract every nth frame of an mp4 file](https://superuser.com/questions/391257/extracting-one-of-every-10-frames-in-a-video-using-vlc-or-ffmpeg).

This command just works fine for me

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,10))" -vsync vfr -q:v 2 img_%03d.jpg
```

However it doesn't seem to leverage my GPU since it only handles around 70fps,

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-06-23-ce297b4 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
  libavcodec     58. 93.100 / 58. 93.100
  libavformat    58. 47.100 / 58. 47.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.100 / 58. 11.100
  libavfilter     7. 86.100 /  7. 86.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.47.100
  Duration: 00:21:58.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2767 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2608 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 153 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0000015dab76e000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'img_%03d.jpg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.47.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.93.100 mjpeg
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame= 2247 fps= 65 q=2.0 size=N/A time=00:15:35.97 bitrate=N/A speed=27.2x
```

and I know my GPU could transcode at up to 900fps when I run transcoding with scaling :

```
D:\wrkfldr\TEST>ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -resize 1280x720 -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 5M output.mp4
ffmpeg version git-2020-06-23-ce297b4 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libgsm --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
  libavcodec     58. 93.100 / 58. 93.100
  libavformat    58. 47.100 / 58. 47.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.100 / 58. 11.100
  libavfilter     7. 86.100 /  7. 86.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.47.100
  Duration: 00:21:58.65, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2767 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2608 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 153 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Codec AVOption resize (Resize (width)x(height)) specified for input file #0 (input.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some decoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.47.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), cuda, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 5000 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.93.100 h264_nvenc
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/5000000 buffer size: 10000000 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 153 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
frame= 6329 fps=970 q=14.0 Lsize=  164909kB time=00:04:24.08 bitrate=5115.5kbits/s speed=40.5x
```

I tried

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,10))" -vsync vfr -q:v 2 img_%03d.jpg
```

But this returns

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_select_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

Also tried

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -vf "select=not(mod(n\,10))" -vsync vfr -q:v 2 img_%03d.jpg
```

But this returns corrupted `jpgs` (Windows can't view them)

Comment: It’s all well and good that your GPU can process a video stream at 900 fps, but consider what’s on the end of your processing pipe: Creating hundreds of files. Possibly on NTFS. // The only thing that could be accelerated is the video _decoding_ part.

Comment: Indeed, I did not forsee that the file creation would be that big of a bottleneck .. I hoped there would be some magic ffmpeg could do for me.